# Make not building dot files before pdf

Tags: makefile, latex

I have the current folder structure for my project

```
.
├── Makefile
└── S6
    ├── CD_CS304.md
    ├── CN_CS306.md
    ├── DAA_CS302.md
    └── graphviz
        └── cs304_compilerphases.dot

2 directories, 5 files
```

I am building separate pdfs for each and every markdown file, here is my Makefile

```
# Generate PDFs from the Markdown source files
#
# In order to use this makefile, you need some tools:
# - GNU make
# - Pandoc

# All markdown files are considered sources
MD_SOURCES := $(wildcard **/*.md)
OUTPUT_PDFS := $(MD_SOURCES:.md=.pdf)
DOT_SOURCES := $(wildcard **/*.dot)
OUTPUT_DOTPNGS := $(DOT_SOURCES:.dot=.png)

all: $(OUTPUT_DOTPNGS) $(OUTPUT_PDFS) 

# Recipe for building png files from dot files
%.png: %.dot
    dot \
        -Tpng $< \
        -o $@

# Recipe for converting a Markdown file into PDF using Pandoc
%.pdf: %.md
    pandoc \
        --variable fontsize=12pt \
        --variable date:"\today" \
        --variable geometry:a4paper \
        --variable documentclass:book \
        --table-of-contents \
        --number-sections \
        --filter pandoc-fignos \
        -f markdown  $< \
        -o $@


.PHONY : clean

clean: $(OUTPUT_PDFS) $(OUTPUT_DOTPNGS)
    $(RM) $^
```

I want to embed the output of the dot program into the latex pdf's but here the Makefile does not make the dot files into png and goes straight into compiling the pdf.

This makes the pdf compilation run into errors as the png files are not present.

Comment: The `wildcard` function only accepts simple globbing.  It doesn't understand advanced globbing like `**` to mean "recursively for all subdirectories".  So `$(wildcard **/*.md)` is really identical to writing `$(wildcard */*.md)`: all `.md` files in a directory immediately below the current directory.

Comment: That seemed to be the case I have changed it to DOT_SOURCES := $(wildcard */*/*.dot) and it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ensure that one file is built before another file, add a dependency.

Change this:

```
%.pdf: %.md
```

to this:

```
%.pdf: %.md $(OUTPUT_DOTPNGS)
```

This dependency says, "Don't build this pdf file unless you've built every png file."